# Neo4j connection issue

Tags: neo4j

I have recently started using neo4j and I'd like to know how can I use neo4j jdbc url? There are few options as mentioned here https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc. However, let's say, one process starts in-memory database and another process wants to use the same db using connection. than how can i use jdbc url jdbc:neo4j:mem or jdbc:neo4j:mem:name ? How  can I get the database name. Also I tried using jdbc:neo4j:file:/home/user/neo/graph.db but it seems neo4j always try to start the server and hence it failed because there is one location of database files. please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what you want to do so that we can help you in achieving that. This question has many questions in it.

Comment: There is a java method which starts the in memory database using GraphdatabaseService. This database is using db file:/pathtodb/.I can start using the graph db using the API. Now, in the same app I have configured connection pool which uses jdbc url to get the connection from the same db file:/pathtodb/. I have configured connection pool using JDBC url. But I am not able to connect to the db using the conn pool API . I'd need help in connecting the db using neo4j driver (using conn pool). Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

*There is a java method which starts the in memory database using GraphdatabaseService. This database is using db file:/pathtodb/*

That is not a in-memory database. You are actually pointing to the file backed neo4j instance. 
You cannot create multiple instances of GraphdatabaseService against the same neo4j file based DB.

**When can we say its a pure in memory startup?**

When you are either using `org.neo4j.test.ImpermanentGraphDatabase` or using `jdbc:neo4j:mem` in case of `neo4j-jdbc`

Comment: Thansk for the explaination. When can we say its a pure in memory startup. newEmbeddedDatabase(String path) requires path and as I understand this path is file system path which is C:\neo4j\neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03\data\graph.db in my case. I'm confused.

Comment: @user2690349 check my updated response. accept this answer if I've answered your question

Comment: @user2690349 do you have any follow up questions?